# Looking for story where weather control makes snow fall once in warm climate

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for a very good story I read many years ago. The story was about a request to a politician that an old dying man would like to see snow fall before he died. The world now had weather control (maybe by controlling sunspots?) but he was in a warm climate (southern California?) and could not be moved and was near death. The man had been instrumental in the early days of weather control. I think the story starts by following the politician who decided to try to honor the man's request and passes a special bill thru the world legislature to make it happen. It then moves to a women (I think) in the weather service who needs to do something radical (in boats on the sun?) to make it happen. I think there were 3 vignettes but I'm forgetting one of them. The story ends with snow falling on 1 acre and the man gets to see the snow before he dies (which may occur at the end of the snowfall). Does anyone else recall this story and could provide title and author?

Comment: When was "many years ago"? It could help us date the story.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The story I remember is definitely [‘The Weather Man’](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55492) by [Theodore L. Thomas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_L._Thomas) ([synopsis](http://everythingisnice.wordpress.com/2010/04/12/the-weather-man-by-theodore-l-thomas/)).

Printed in [Isaac Asimov Presents The Great SF Stories 24 (1962)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov_Presents_The_Great_SF_Stories_24_%281962%29)

Answer (score 6):

L Thomas's novelette "The Weather Man" (June 1962 Analog), - See more at: http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/weather_control#sthash.c6oiuviS.dpuf